# Customize Woocommerce Invoice

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, invoice

I have built an ecommerce website using WooCommerce.I need to generate invoice for all my customer orders.I have tried a few plugins to generate the same but the invoices aren't satisfactory for me.Alongwith the the Product Name,Quantity and Price I also desire to display the Regular Price and the Sale Price of each product.Please Help!

Thank You! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin from Woothemes:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-print-invoice-packing-list/
And modify the invoices by customizing your template (see the section "Creating Custom Templates" in the aforementioned webpage).